# Graph dashboard for PHP/Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, plotly, dashboard

Newbie in PHP/Symfony here.

In Python I was used to the ease of [Dash/Plotly](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/Portal/) and **I am searching for any dashboard with similar features for PHP/Symfony**: tabbed pages, realtime update, linked charts, user interaction.

I only found a couple of packages to use plotly.js in PHP/Symfony: [biworks/plotly-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/biworks/plotly-bundle?query=dash%20plotly) and [turek/yii2-plotly](https://packagist.org/packages/turek/yii2-plotly).

Is there any complete solution (even a Dash/Plotly wrapper) to create a whole dashboard for data visualization in PHP/Symfony?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Is it because we risk a war on opinions, no effort in the search, unclear question or something else? If I don't know which tool to use, how should I ask for help? Please add a reason, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puh, I've mostly been integrating outside code in order to generate graphs.
My favorite is
https://developers.google.com/chart,
which you only need to pass data via ajax and set a regular reload for the ajax-call.

Answer (score 0):

In symfony you have so called `bundles` from symfony or 3rd parties.
One which fits your specs would be the [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html).

Comment: This is interesting to create a dashboard, as I can understand. What I miss is the integration data-charts/dashboard. I don't understand how to make the two parts interact. With Dash/Plotly it is all fully integrated (I have been spoiled, I know).